# Need to parse php array in ajax success callback

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I am working to implement ajax based pagination in CodeIgniter. I need to update the table content on the page when the user clicks on next pagination link.

Data is coming from php multidimension array `$incomplete.Like` `$incomplete->name`, `$incomplete->test` etc.
What I need to do is to parse `$incomplete` PHP array in ajax success call so that we can replace the content. I don't have an idea what to write in success function to parse PHP array (`$incomplete`) here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var record = <?php echo json_encode($incomplete); ?>; // this is a multidimensional array

$(function(){
    $('body').on('click','ul#search_page_pagination>li>a',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();  // prevent default behaviour for anchor tag
      var Pagination_url = $(this).attr('href'); // getting href of <a> tag

    $.ajax({
      url:Pagination_url,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,

      success: function() 
      { 

      }

    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your success function with this

```
success: function(response) {

}
```

the response argument will contain the json output by your php script.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to parse.

```
$.ajax({
url:Pagination_url,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
success: function(data) {
alert(data[0]);
}
```

You can access your data like data.var name